# Javascript: Setting object keys with loop given existing object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, for-loop, key-value

My objective is to create a function which returns a new object consisting of keys as names and values as the players numbers:

```
var newObj = {"Brandon Bass": 2, "Tarik Black":19,...}
```

I have this object:

```
  var playerObj = {
  players: [{
      name: "Brandon Bass",
      number: 2,
      stats: {
        points: 2.5
      }
    },

    {
      name: "Tarik Black",
      number: 19,
      stats: {
        points: 2.5
      }
    }, {
      name: "Anothy Broqn",
      number: 11,
      stats: {
        points: 4.8
      }
    },

    {
      name: "Kobe Bryant",
      number: 22,
      stats: {
        points: 5.6
      }
    }
  ]};
```

This is [my most recent attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/p82kkL61/). Is this possible to do?

```
for (var key in playerObj.players) {
  var newObj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < playerOjb.players.length; i++) {
    newObj[playerObj.players[i]] = playerObj.players[key].number;
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

Comment: Include your code *in the question*

Comment: `return newObj` will end the loop immediately after the first player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looping arrays, use a standard `for` loop, not a `for..in`, then simply create the object as you were:

```
var newObj = {}
for (var i = 0; i < playerObj.players.length; i++) {
    newObj[playerObj.players[i].name] = playerObj.players[i].number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) that array like this,

```
var newObj = playerObj.players.reduce(function(old,itm){
   old[itm.name] = itm.number
   return old;
}, {});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p82kkL61/1/)

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you